# Can't change branch: merge conflict because of (already?) untracked file

Tags: git, version-control, branch, merge-conflict-resolution

I already had the problem that I couldn't check out a branch (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569291/cant-switch-branch-untracked-working-tree-file-because-of-case-insensitivity)). After I forced the checkout (`git checkout master -f`) and did the merging and tagging, I now want to switch to the *develop* branch back. This is what I get:

```
git checkout develop
MyProject.userprefs: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

This is what `git status` gives:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 78 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    deleted by us:   MyProject.userprefs

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I had the file `MyProject.userprefs` in the beginning, but removed it from *develop* branch and added it to `.gitignore`. Now the file seems not to be ignored in the *master* branch.

What is also interesting is that the file seems to be tracked twice in the index `git ls-files --stage`:

```
100644 b16bd8d4e57de7705a5a388d045fed7376a1b175 1   MyProject.userprefs
100644 ef238f895ca1b80f10cfcd45349d82df925ff482 3   MyProject.userprefs
```

Should I simply delete *MyProject.userprefs*? But the IDE needs that. Should I recreate the index in the *master* branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the solution described in [Resolving a merge conflict from the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/#resolving-by-removing-the-file):

```
git rm MyProject.userprefs
```

Now I was able to change the branch.